# Keynote version 8.3 how to alter image opacity.. only shows gallery/arrange and not style tab?

Tags: keynote

Please can you help?  I want to fade out an image on a keynote presentation but in the version I have (which is 8.3) there isn't the style tab.  How can I change the opacity of the image?  Is there a tool elsewhere within keynote?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you want a fade animation?  The dissolve animation will do that. Just vary the length of time to suit. Unless I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

To fade an image in Keynote, use the Dissolve animation.

Steps:

- Select the desired image
- Go to Animations
- Select Build Out
- Choose the **Dissolve** animation
- Set the desired timing and whether to animate on click or with another action

For more information on animations, check out the [**Animate Objects**](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph16960) in the Help menu.

[image: Image Fade]